# How to put a comma separated value from a column in a table into SQL IN operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table which has a column in which I am storing a comma separated text with single quotes for each of the comma separated values. These values are employee IDs. This is how it looks

[image]

Now, I have a SQL query wherein I need to put the value from this column into a SQL IN operator. Something like this:

```
select * 
from EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
where EMPLOYEEID IN (select CM_CONFIG_VALUE 
                     from ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T 
                     where CM_CONFIG_KEY like 'ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID'
                    )
```

But this, does not work, the query when executed returns 0 rows whereas if I execute the query normally like below, it works.

```
select * 
from EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
where EMPLOYEEID IN('9F3DD4B791554DDE','C9B90D62851D43AB','828CB9E6204B4DDC')
```

Please suggest what I should do here. I have tried using substring to remove the first and the last character as well assuming that single quotes might be the issue, but that does not work either.

Comment: What `SQL Server` version you are using ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma  SQL Server 2014

Comment: You can use STRING_SPLIT function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15. But I think it was introduced in SQL Server 2015.

Comment: _in which I am storing a comma separated text with single quotes for each of the comma separated values_. Dont. Store them one item per row.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from EMPLOYEE_MASTER where EMPLOYEEID IN(select EMPLOYEEID from ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T where CM_CONFIG_KEY like 'ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID')
```

column should be same in where COLUMNNAME IN (select COLUMNNMAE from tablename)

Comment: The reason why I have used column name CM_CONFIG_VALUE in the where clause is that, CM_CONFIG_VALUE is supposed to store the comma separated list of employee IDs and my requirement is such that I need to find out data based on the employee IDs in that column. EMPLOYEEID column does not exist in the table ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T.

Comment: ok.Then in that case use join .In query will not work in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp varible and then use `exec` command to get the desired result.

```sql
declare @temp varchar(200)
select @temp=CM_CONFIG_VALUE 
                from ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T 
                     where CM_CONFIG_KEY like 'ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID'

exec('select * 
from EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
where EMPLOYEEID IN (' + @temp + ')')
```

Comment: I have tested it on a temp table and was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @comma CHAR;

SET @comma = ','
SET @ID = (select CM_CONFIG_VALUE 
                     from ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T 
                     where CM_CONFIG_KEY like %ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID% + @comma);

Create table #temp (EMPLOYEEID varchar(500))
WHILE CHARINDEX(@comma, @ID) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@ID, 0, CHARINDEX(@comma, @ID))
    SET @ID = SUBSTRING(@ID, CHARINDEX(@comma, @ID) + 1, LEN(@ID))

    Insert into #temp
    select @Number

END
select * 
from EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
where EMPLOYEEID IN(select EMPLOYEEID from #temp)
```

Comment: With this approach, the query that is created at the end is select * from EMPLOYEE_MASTER where EMPLOYEE_ID IN(select CM_CONFIG_VALUE wfrom ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T where CM_CONFIG_KEY like  'ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID%') and this again returns 0 rows.

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting it in your query is because your inner query returns only one row. So your query searches for `'9F3DD4B791554DDE','C9B90D62851D43AB','828CB9E6204B4DDC'` as  as single record.

If your `compatibility level` is greater than or equal to 130 you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` function. Then your query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE_MASTER
WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN 
    (SELECT value AS empid
    FROM ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T CROSS APPLY string_split(CM_CONFIG_VALUE, ',' )
    WHERE CM_CONFIG_KEY LIKE 'ATT_BIOMETRIC_OU_ID' )
```

What this actually does is, it splits the CM_CONFIG_VALUE with ',' and returns them as rows. This is the value column I have referred. Then you use them with the IN clause.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Direct `IN` condition will not work here. You have split your string before searching. You can do that with `XML` options in `SQL SERVER 2014`

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE EMPID IN (
      SELECT a.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')
           FROM (
                 SELECT x = CAST('<a>' + 
                 REPLACE(REPLACE(CM_CONFIG_VALUE , ',', '</a><a>'),'''','') + '</a>' AS XML  ) 
                 FROM ADL_CONFIG_MAST_T
               -- WHERE <your_condition>
                ) m
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/a') a(c))
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a021fdaa48f06b1da3383b707d7581d1)

For the version 2016 and above you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#compatibility-level-130) with Compatibility level 130